# Rotating Image in C# Desktop Application from Image Location Only

Tags: c#, sql, image, desktop

I am writing a C# desktop application that involves importing images from a digital camera, and saving them in a SQL Compact Edition database. I'm not saving the actual images in the database, but the image file path (to save database space). I'm then pulling that image file path from the database and setting the Image Location property of a Picture Box to that path, for display purposes.

My question is this... I would like to add a button that will allow the user to rotate the image after import. Is there a way to do this without creating a new image? I know of the RotateFlip method, but it only works with type Image. Basically, I want to rotate the image linked the file path instead of creating an image from that path, then rotating it. I would love some ideas. Thanks!

Comment: You want to change the image file (which is lying) on your hard disk?

Comment: No you can not do. What you can do is have two files for each image one original one rotated or... Create an equivalent image, rotate it and save to original file

Answer (score 0):

You can't rotate an image given it's path unless you load the image first.

By the way, there was no need to include information regarding the database you are using, that information has nothing to do with your problem.